# Duplicating data inside a .csv file changing its format

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file looking like:

```
                X      XB          XC           O       P
  A312      76.55     -           -           -       -  
  B313      175.4   62.28       32.62       8.189   121.2
  J314      176.5   53.34       40.77       8.277   124.6
  L315      177.9   55.29       41.44       8.427   125.5
  T316      174.7   59.47       63.43       8.264   116.1
  ...
  G378      10.2    58.91       40.13       7.646   126.7
```

As you can see, delimiters are blank spaces only and not all values are available for each row.

My goal is to obtain the same exact data with the following format:

```
   312 A   X   76.55
   313 B   X   175.4
   313 B   XB  62.28
   313 B   XC  32.62
   ...
   378 G   O   7.646
   378 G   P   126.7
```

Until now, I managed to read in the file with pandas and isolate all columns:

```
import pandas as pd
raw_id = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", delim_whitespace = True, header = None, skiprows = [0], usecols = [0], index_col = False)

# same lines, different usecols index for each column.

print(raw_id.to_string(index = False, header = False))
```

This is a beginning, but I have two large problems for which I cannot really find a solution.

1) How do I split A312, B313... and re-express them as specified in the above mentioned new format, i.e. 312 A etc.?

2) How do I link each column value to its numeric anchor, repeating the integers for as long as the columns display values, and skipping when I find "-"? I guess some `for` loops are needed here, but I could not manage.

Many thanks to whoever can help with this task!

Comment: `A312` is a string so you can use string functions - ie. slicing, concatenating. Maybe you should use module `csv` instead of `pandas` and work with every row separatelly.

Answer (score 2):

Start by removing the missing values:

```
import numpy as np
x = raw_id.replace('-', np.nan).stack().reset_index()
```

Then, split the names:

```
x = x.join(x['level_0'].str.extract(r'(\D)(\d+)'), lsuffix='_')
```

Finally, remove the redundant column:

```
x.drop('level_0', axis=1, inplace=True)
#   level_1     0_  0    1
#0        X  76.55  A  312
#1        X  175.4  B  313
#2       XB  62.28  B  313
#3       XC  32.62  B  313
#4        O  8.189  B  313
#...
```

You may want to rename the columns appropriately before saving the results to a CSV file.

Comment: Thanks @DYZ! Very useful. I am actually having problems with the slash character. I am on a Mac machine right now, does it change anything?

Comment: For example, using a forward slash as I usually do, yields this error message: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas.

Comment: Still throws a bunch of errors. My code right now:

[ import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd

  raw_id = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", delim_whitespace = True, header = None, skiprows = [0], usecols = [0], index_col = False)

  x = raw_id.replace('-', np.nan).stack().reset_index()
  x = x.join(x['level_0'].str.extract(r'(\D)(\d+)'), lsuffix='_')
  x.drop('level_0', axis=1, inplace=True)
  print(x)]
Can you spot what's wrong?

Comment: "_a bunch of errors_" is not helpful. Please explain.

Comment: The error I refer to is the one mentioned above, i.e.: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`. Following update on the piece of code you gently provided did not solve the issue.

Comment: Your CSV file has a header line. Why do you pass `header = None` to the reader?

Comment: I tried to edit the `pd.read_csv` arguments after I reported the first message declaring the error, but I could not solve the issue. Is there a walk around or something? Code lines `x.drop('level_0', axis=1, inplace=True)` and `x = raw_id.replace('-', np.nan).stack().reset_index()` work, the problem arises when trying to split strings and integers with `x = x.join(x['level_0'].str.extract(r'(\D)(\d+)'), lsuffix='_')`